# .Net folder compilation tool

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder with many .csproj files. I have many folders like this.
I have a big solution with all my projects in it, but most of the time i just want to compile all the projects in one of the folders. 
Is there a tool that I can use to let's say right click on the folder-->"Compile all"?

Comment: Yes, in Visual Studio, right-click the folder node and select "Build". If they're not grouped using Solution Folders that represent their structure on disk, then make them so.

Comment: you can use MsBuild that is being used in Visual Studio also, that is also accessible over cmd you can easily write batch files to compile your whole solution or single projects for that matter.

Comment: wait.. are you using Visual Studio? My answer kind of depends on that..

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, sound good. Now i just need to see if someone already wrapped it.

Comment: @Default. Yes i am...

Comment: @Itay.B I just looked does not seem so, but building a custom context menu using known command line commands should be doable

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, It's for sure not too hard to implement. I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel unless i have to :)

Comment: @Itay.B hm i would have wrote up sth for you but cant get it complete right now, if you have msbuild installed `msbuild D:\path\to\project\projectname.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCpu` this command should do it, my problem right now is I dunno how to get projects file name easily from the folder name that you rightclicked as I never did such context menu extensions before ;) Hope this helps a bit

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, you know what? I'll look into it and if i end up making a utility like this, I'll share with you.

Comment: @Itay.B awesome, coz your question got me into wanting this now too ;) similarly one could also implement a `deploy`-button which i also would like ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, Greate. I'll be in touch soon.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try Building the Solution that contains all the projects?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what i need. i want only one of my layers. say the DAL layer. i want to compile all my DAL projects.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

Select all of the projects in the solution explorer that you want to build, right click and select "Build Selection"

or

Add a/several build configuration(s) that only builds the projects that you are interested in

or

Create a new solution file with the projects that are grouped, which will only build those (the solution file can exist in the same location as the current one)

Comment: well, with buildconfigurations it's just as easy as: `Ctrl+B O` and stepping up and down in a list. Then click `Build` whatever that is mapped to (`Ctrl+Shift+B` perhaps). That would be my preferred way to do it

Comment: I mean `Alt+B O` (to access it from the menu)

Comment: it's a matter of right click (your wanted context menu), left click (select) **vs** left click (build configuration|combobox), left click (select the wanted build configuration), Buildshortcut (build project). Is one action more that expensive..?

Comment: @Default yes it is, Besides it might very well be 2 more actions indeed, because one would not have to start visual studio ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste based on the OPs first comment, right click "compile all" would IMO be in visual studio. But I catch your drift. Basically, the OP is looking for a batch script that does `msbuild proj.csproj` multiple times.